# Meaning of おられる姿

Tags: grammar, politeness, subsidiary-verbs

> 小池百合子都知事の頑張っている姿、私は最大限評価している。ある意味の古い政治と向き合って戦って**おられる姿**、共鳴もする。

How do you understand おられる姿?

Answer (score 6):

It is not 「おられる姿{すがた}」 that you should be looking at.

It is:

> 「戦{たたか}っておられる姿」

「戦って**おられる**」＝「戦って**いらっしゃる**」

Both are ***expressions of respect***.  The plain form is 「戦って**いる**」.

「戦っておられる姿」 means "***how she looks when fighting***".  「姿」 is a very difficult word to translate. "***the way someone looks***", "***someone's appearance***", etc.

> "I also sympathize with the way she looks when fighting against the old, in a sense,  style of politics."

Comment: 「姿」 is hard to translate in this context.
I think it is almost an idealized symbolic form/figure rather than the literal physical appearance.